# How to break a for loop from inside of a fuction

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, break

i have the following code

```
function do_function($name, $value, $age){

    $sql = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("INSERT into `table` Values('','$name','$value','$age')"));

    if (!$sql) {
        // basicly will return false on duplicate key
        //do something to break the calling for_loop ?
        //i`ve tried break(); and continue(); but this will break/skip just the
        //function not the for loop
    }
}

$presetnumber = 25;
for($x = 0; $x <= $presetnumber; $x++){
    do_function($name[$x], $value[$x], $age[$x]);
    //return something on duplicate key to break the for loop ???
}
```

so i wannt to be able to just skip the entire loop if there is a duplicate key not just the function?

How can i do this, i don`t seem to understand quite entirely why break(); or continue(); is not working.

Please note that this is just a sample code to give you an ideea what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: Just return true or false from the function and put it in a if statement and if true or so then break the loop?!

Comment: Answer it @Rizier123.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return TRUE or FALSE in your function and then you can do a simple check in your loop like this:

(Pseudo code):

```
function do_function($name, $value, $age) {

    //your stuff

    if(!$sql)
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;

}
```

```
for($x = 0; $x <= $presetnumber; $x++){
    if(do_function($name[$x], $value[$x], $age[$x]))  //breaks the loop if you  return TRUE
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`break` will not work outside of the for loop.  It must be inside the loop to be activated.  So you could add a function like:

```
for(foo; bar; baz) {
  if (checkForBreak()) {break};
}
```

Also, if you're working in PHP then `break` is a statement, not a function.  So it's `break;`, not `break();`.

Comment: yeah right sorry for misspelling but it is not working, i have tryied it but no success, also continue; and break; or break(1); still no success, it keeps going on :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe your SQL query is always returning TRUE. Replace this:

```
$sql = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("INSERT into `table` ... "));
```

With this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT into `table` Values('','$name','$value','$age')");
```

I would also suggest for you to start using `mysqli` rather than `mysql` since it is deprecated

Comment: yeap you are right i solved it now but this was just a sample i put together i wil rectify the mistake ;)